# Euro Trip on December

Tags: schengen, europe, ireland

I am from india and I will be travelling to Ireland in ICT Visa on November. I need to travel to other European countries on the month of December. Kindly let me know the procedure. I need to know where I can apply for visa and how much time it will take to get it stamped and other procedures.

Comment: Procedure for what? Check in? Buying tickets? Getting visas? Could you look at the [help] and please edit your question to be more specific and expand a bit on detail.

Comment: Also try to refrain from using ALL CAPS, it's considered shouting online :(

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply for a normal Schengen tourist visa for the other countries to which you wish to travel; or in the case of UK a normal tourist UK visa (UK is not part of the Schengen zone).

Your company transfer visa does not avail you any permanent residency status or otherwise in the guest country - the bottom line to this is that you are just like any normal visitor except you are coming as a temporary worker.

You can read more about your visa type at the [INIS website](http://inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Employment%20(Permits%20etc.)).

Comment: yes I agree, whether I will be able to get the visa stamped in one or two weeks if I apply in Ireland for multiple entry Schengen tourist visa. Kindly brief it.

Comment: It can take upto 15 calendar days for a Schengen visa - unless there is cause for further review of your application in which case it will be longer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any pre-requisites for multiple entry  Schengen tourist visa for Indians.

Comment: Yes, of course. Check with the embassy of the destination country you wish to apply. You need to provide bank statements of 6 months, travel itinerary (including hotel/flight reservations); in addition to the normal requirements (passport valid for 6 months after your trip, photo, application, application fees, travel insurance, etc. etc.)

Comment: If anyone have done the same before please share your experience. I need to visit France, Czech Republic, Swiss , Spain and Germany.